# Jasmine не загружает контент фрейма

Tags: javascript, iframe, юнит-тесты, jasmine

Я пытаюсь получить доступ к контенту фрейма (сам фрейм содержится в файле iframe.html на сайте, не кросс-доменный фрейм) в Jasmine тестах.
Сам файл iframe.html имеет такую разметку

```
<iframe style="width:100%; height: 100%;" class="frame">
    <html lang="en">
        <head> .... </head>
        <body> ... </body>
    </html>
</frame>
```

JS

```
    describe('DOM of color elements checking', function () {
    jasmine.getFixtures().fixturesPath = 'base/tests/units/js/fixtures';
    jasmine.getFixtures().load('frame.html');
    var fixtureIframe = readFixtures('iframe.html'); //here is iframe HTML
    $('.workspace__iframe-wrapper').append(fixtureIframe);

    $('iframe').load(function(){

       var body = $('.frame').contents().find('body');
       console.log(body);
    });
});
```

Но контент в фрейм не загружается.
Почему это происходит?

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что он задан не по-русски

Comment: Если для Вас, уважаемы тутанхамон, проблема прочитать вопрос на английском, то я могу перевести его:
"Я пытаюсь получить доступ к контенту фрейма в тестах Jasmine (... дальше идет пример моего кода...) Но в фрейм не загружаются данные. Почему это происходит?"

Comment: @Gennadiy Shvedko, tutankhamun всего-лишь руководствуется правилами данного ресурса. Отредактируйте свой вопрос.

Comment: @GennadiyShvedko для вопросов на английском есть http://stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Как много было потрачено энергии для того чтобы "научить жить", лучше бы на вопрос ответ дали или подсказали где искать)))

Comment: @Gennadiy Shvedko, вы загружаете в iframe страницу с другого домена?

Comment: нет, в тесте я просто добавляю HTML сайта с другого домена, этот HTML уже записан в iframe.html

Comment: Попробуйте обратиться к фрейму по id, а не по классу. И проверьте доступ к фрейму, если функцию повесить на клик кнопки, вручную.

Comment: Также полезно будет дополнительно посмотреть что происходит со стороны HTTP, какие запросы отправляются и что отвечает сервер

Comment: @GennadiyShvedko а вы уверены, что контент во фрейм не загружается? Может он просто _не доступен_? Есть у меня такое чувство, что у вас проблема с кросс-доменными фреймами.

Comment: @Dmitriy Simushev, мне уже ответили, что контент точно не с другого сайта. Смотрите комментарий выше.

Comment: @Visman, если я правильно понял логику теста, то _сначала_ создается iframe с `src` на другом домене, а уже после его загрузки (`$('iframe').load`) происходит попытка обращения к содержимому. Так что это в чистом виде _кросдоменные фреймы_ со всеми вытекающими.

Comment: По поводу загрузки контента
$('.frame').contents().find('body') здесь я получаю данные, но там пусто. У меня такое впечатление что именно Jasmine(или Karma которую я тоже использую) очищает контент фрейма, т.к. даже "тупая" вставка HTML в тег фрейма не приносит результата

Comment: @Dmitriy Simushev, значит автор вопроса вводит нас в заблуждение и там действительно фрейм с другого домена.

Comment: нет, в тесте я просто добавляю HTML сайта с другого домена, этот HTML уже записан в iframe.html –  Gennadiy Shvedko 28 мин. назад
Даже если я уберу атрибут src, то результат не поменяется

Comment: Где у вас хранится iframe.html? На вашем сайте или на другом? Что у вас прописано в src при тесте?

Comment: @GennadiyShvedko не надо вводить людей в заблуждение! Что вы понимаете под "_HTML уже записан в iframe.html_"? Приведите содержимое iframe в тексте вопроса. Вы ведь понимаете, что содержимое в iframe **все равно будет загружаться** из  `src` после его отрисовки? Единственное исключение -- если в браузере отключена поддержка iframe

Comment: iframe.html хранится на сайте, src пустой (вернее его вообще нет). Вот приблизительное содержание iframe.html

    <iframe style="width:100%; height: 100%;" class="frame">
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>....</head>
    <body>......</body>
    <html>
    </iframe>`

Comment: @GennadiyShvedko, разметку в текст вопроса, пожалуйста.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev разметку в текст вопроса добавил

Comment: То есть вы в фрейм загружаете файл который содержит в себе еще один фрейм?

Comment: @Visman Я уже и сам запутался в этих правках. Нет я в файл frame.html в тег div добавляю содержимое файла iframe.html который и содержит фрейм (никакого фрейма в фрейме нет). Вопрос поправил.

Comment: @GennadiyShvedko вы бы определились есть там атрибут `src` или нет. Это **принципиальный** момент, от которого зависит _почему_ не работает ваш код.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev Нет, там нет src. Но даже если я его туда вставлю и не буду подгружать содержимое файла iframe.html (это уже будет кросс-доменный фрейм), то загрузка контента все равно не происходит.

Comment: @GennadiyShvedko а с чего вы взяли, что это _вы_ управляете подгрузкой контента. Этим управляет браузер вне зависимости от вашего желания. Есть `src` -- контент загрузится, нет -- будет загружена заглушка вида `<html><head></head><body></body></html>`.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev Спасибо за информацию, это я уже понял. Но вопрос остается открытым. Я поставил атрибут src, но контент в фрейм не загрузился

Comment: @GennadiyShvedko значит вы снова вернулись к проблеме кросс-доменных фреймов. Перед тем как что-то делать -- разберитесь что именно вы хотите сделать. Не надо скакать от одного решения к другому.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо всем за попытки угадать мои мысли))) Но я нашел решение. Во-первых в Karma настроил роутинг на тот же  хост и порт где отдаю контент фрейма, т.о. я избавился от кросс-домености. Во-вторых до меня дошло, что фрейм загружается после старта тестов, т.е. тесты уже запустились а фрейм еще ничего не содержит. Поэтому я воспользовался рецептом для проверки ассинхронности

JS

```
beforeEach(function(done){

    jasmine.getFixtures().fixturesPath = 'base/tests/units/js/fixtures';
    jasmine.getFixtures().load('frame.html');
    interval = jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL;
    jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 15000;

    intId = setInterval(function() {

        $('#frame').load(function(){
            done();
        });
      }, 500);
});
```

После этой манипуляции я добился нужного результата - тесты стали запускаться после загрузки фрейма.

Answer (score 3):

Разметка, которая указывается между тегами `<iframe>` и `</iframe>` используется только если браузер не поддерживает `iframe` (либо эта опция отключена). Во всех других случаях будет происходить загрузка документа, указанного в атрибуте `src` (который у вас не указан).

Отсутствие атрибута `src` приводит к тому, что браузер на самом деле не загружает содержимое фрейма и не вызывает события `onload`([пруф](http://jsfiddle.net/x1a3a2z4/)). Фактически в iframe у вас будет что-то вроде:

```
<html><head></head><body></body></html>
```

Самое интересное, контент, который вы указали между тегами `<iframe>` и `</iframe>` будет *проигнорирован*, потому, что фреймы в браузере включены, но атрибута `src` нет. А вот и [пруф](http://jsfiddle.net/xz1huzqw/).

Как результат: ваши тесты не работают. Я не представляю, что именно вы хотите тестировать (никакой конкретики в вопросе нет), но вы делаете это абсолютно не правильно.

Comment: Все же на этом сайте есть телепаты ;)

Comment: @Visman, и все-таки я не угадал :)

Comment: Ответ же как правильным был помечен О_о

Comment: @Visman, Больше нет :) Ждем, пока автор отметит свой ответ как правильный.

Comment: @Visman я пока не могу голосовать поэтому не могу отблагодарить автора данного ответа, но этот ответ не полный значит не могу сказать что он решил мою проблему на 100%

Comment: @GennadiyShvedko чтобы дать полный ответ на вопрос в текущей постановке нужно быть телепатом.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev поэтому я и не ставлю свой ответ в плюс)))

Comment: @Visman я не гонюсь за рейтингами, но как я могу поставить что ответ решил проблему если это не так?